# How to control a python program from a webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, windows

I have written a python program that runs on Windows 10 and allows the user to create and maintain a family tree in the form of a website which can be uploaded to a server on completion. The first page of the website has a square for each person and when those squares are clicked it takes the user to a page holding detailed information about that person.
This python program allows the user to choose which person's details are to be edited by moving between relatives (goto Mother, goto Child, etc.). This is rather cumbersome, it would be far more convenient if the user could see the first page of the website on their windows machine, click on a person in the family tree, and start editing that person. However, I cannot think of a way to do this because webpages are precluded from interacting with the operating system for security reasons.

So my question is: can anyone recommend a method that would allow a python program to know what square in a webpage has been clicked? All code is running on the user's machine.

Extract from html produced by the python program:

```
<style>
.person-3-6 {
position: absolute;
top: 1420px;
left: 3755px;
width:  150px;
height: 70px;
}
.person-3-7 {
position: absolute;
top: 1420px;
left: 5020px;
width:  150px;
height: 70px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class='person-3-6'>John Christy
<br><br><br>1845 - 1930<a href='Root/Mother/Mother/Father/index.html'><span class='link'></span></a>
</div>
<div class='person-3-7'>Ann Smith
<br><br><br>1851 - 1924<a href='Root\Mother\Mother\Mother/index.html'><span class='link'></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the python application hosts the browser window itself then it and the window can "talk" to each other.

The Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF3) project lets a C++ application host Chromium (the base for Google Chrome, MS Edge, etc.)

https://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php?sid=777c87a50f89432bc1923df7afdc7025

CEFPython is a project to adapt CEF to Python:

https://pypi.org/project/cefpython3/

https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython

The CEFPython developer is active in the CEF discussion forum above.

What many people do is use one of the two included sample browsers (CEFClient, CEFSimple) as a starting point.  Either working with the existing projects and adding customizations, or creating a new empty project and copying over files from client or simple.